# jquery variable as div ID or class

Tags: jquery, class, variables, html

```
var $name = ('div#amuchlongername');

    $('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="$name"></div>');
```

Obviously I know this code is wrong lol, but I'm fairly knew to jQuery and I can't seem to find anything about this.

How would one go about achieving a variable name inside a div id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would go about it in the same way as normal JavaScript (since it's just a string passed to jQuery).

```
var name = 'amuchlongername'
$('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="' + name + '"></div>');
```

`name` is just a normal JavaScript variable and can be anything. The `$` is an alias for `jQuery`. When you do `$('#wrapper')` you are calling jQuery to access the element with the Id of `wrapper`.

I've made a jsFiddle to show it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Xs45x/1/ I've just updated it to put the variable inside the div too, so you can see what it's doing.

Comment: I havent tested it, but it seems to make sense. So you don't need the (''); for the variables either then?

Comment: Ideal, makes sense now. It's always the most simple thing haha. I'll get there in the end. =]

Comment: Great! Note that `name` is just a string. If you wanted to use jQuery on the new element you could do `var $myNewDiv = $('#amuchlongername')` or even just `var $myNewDiv = $(name);` since name is a string. As mentioned in the comment by Jamiec, the `$` isn't required on the variable name but is a nice notation for jQuery objects.

Answer (score 0):

i'm no js expert but try

```
var $name = ('div#amuchlongername');

('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="' + $name + '"></div>');
```

also i don't *think* you need the $ sign for variables. Might be wrong

Comment: You're correct. In JavaScript you don't need to have $ on variable names. However, to access the element using jQuery (usually by the $) you'll need the $ on the ('#wrapper') bit - i.e. $('#wrapper')

Comment: Using a $variablename is just a convention when dealing with jQuery objects - and a good one IMO.

Comment: +1 Not a convention I knew about but it makes sense for the jQuery objects - thanks. In this case though, the variable is just a normal string.